# On fixed point probability in discrete logarithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fixed-point-theorems, cryptography

Fix an integer $n>2$.

> **Question.** What is the probability that, for a given $h\in\Bbb Z_n,$ there is no $$x\in[0,\varphi(n)-1]\cap\Bbb Z$$ such that
> $h^{x\bmod\varphi(n)}\equiv x\bmod n$?

Comment: What is $\phi (p)$, and why is this tagged as fixed-point-theorems?

Comment: https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/brizolis6.pdf

Comment: Do you mean $h\in \Bbb Z_n$ instead of  $h\in \Bbb Z_p$?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an answer but some additional information.

The problem about fixed  points of discrete logarithms is  known the **Brizolis problem**. In particular for the average number of solutions
$$N(p)=\frac{1}{\varphi(p-1)}\sum_g\left|\{0\le x\le p-1:g^x=x\pmod p\}\right|$$ is known that (Grechnikov, 2012, PhD thesis; published in [Two-side estimates of the number of fixed points of a discrete logarithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103%2FS0027132212030011)) $N(p)=1+S(p)$, where
$$-C(\varepsilon)p^{-1/4+\varepsilon}\le S(p)\le \exp(C'\mathrm{Li}((\log p)^{c\frac{\log\log\log\log p}{\log\log\log p}})).$$

Answer (score 1):

This is more a collection of numerical experiments than an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

I've reinterpreted the question slightly; hopefully this keeps to the spirit of the OP's intent.

- First, it feels more natural (to me) to take $x$ from $[0,n-1]$ rather than $[0,\phi(n)-1]$, so the following experiments consider that case.
- Second, the question as posed isn't probabilistic: for a given $n,h$, the answer is deterministically "yes" or "no".  To address that, let $A(N)$ be the number of fixed points if we select $h$ uniformly at random from $[0,n-1]$ (so, $A(N)$ is a random variable).

We can then consider:
$$L_{all}(c)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Pr[A(n)=c]$$
where $c$ is a count of the number of fixed points.  So, if $c=0$, we're asking about the probability of no fixed points; if $c=3$, we're asking about the probability that, for a randomly chosen $h$, that there are exactly 3 fixed points as $x$ varies.

Note: there is no reason to think that this limit actually exists.

Rather than considering the limit over all $n$, we can restrict to, for example the primes.  Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of primes, and let
$$L_{primes}(c)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in\mathcal{P}} \Pr[A(n)=c]$$

Now, if we pretend that $h^x \bmod n$ is a uniformly random draw from $[0,n-1]$, then the probability of a fixed point is $1/n$.  In that case, the distribution of the number of fixed points would be a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=1$, so we would have
$$L_{primes}(c)=\frac{1}{e(c!)}$$
(In particular, the probability of no fixed points is $1/e\approx 0.36788$.)

We can estimate $L_{primes}$ through the Monte Carlo method: we choose some large $n$ (I took all prime $n$ from 20,000 to 24,000), select a few $h$ for each $n$ (I took 100) and measure the fraction of $h$ with $c=0,1,2,...$ fixed points.  My experiment matches the "uniform draw" model extremely tightly:
[image]
(It's actually a little hard to tell that there are two lines plotted there.)

At the other extreme, we can consider the limit across smooth numbers. 
I took all the numbers between $20,000$ and $124,000$ whose largest prime factor was at most 11 and did the same Monte Carlo experiment.  Let $L_{smooth}(c)$ be the corresponding limit.
The plot of $L_{smooth}(c)$ is quite different:
[image]

To get some sense of why this these cases are so different, we can consider $\Pr[A(n)>0]$ for particular values of $n$.  If we range over the primes, this probability hovers around 0.63 (i.e., 1-1/e), give or take 0.2:
[image]
On the other hand, if we range over smooth numbers, we frequently have $\Pr[A(n)>0] = 1$ (which never happens in the prime case):
[image]
Be warned that these probability estimates are Monte Carlo sampled, so may not be exactly 1.  Nevertheless, the difference is pretty striking.